# Problem with Discord.js code, "process exited with code 1" & "Uncaught Error Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir"

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I was updating a really basic card collecting bot when I realized somewhere along the way I broke it somehow. I'm a rookie at coding so I don't really know what the problem is and would like to know for future reference (this is the error I am getting):

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\index.js
Uncaught Error Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir './commands/balance.js'
    at readdirSync (fs:1450:3)
    at client.handleCommands (c:\Users\theon\Downloads\tsarevna\functions\handlers\handleCommands.js:12:18)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\theon\Downloads\tsarevna\index.js:23:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:17:47)
Process exited with code 1
```

I found some duplicated stuff in the code which I thought could be part of the problem, it wasn't. It was prompting me to do "npm audit fix" in which I did and it fixed some errors, but not the current one I am getting. Again, I am new at this and I don't want to damage the code even more than I probably already have done, any type of help would be appreciated!

Comment: The relative path `./commands/balance.js` is invalid

Comment: Hi, the error clearly says that `balance.js`  is not a directory. Post  relevant parts of your code,  and take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will increase your chance to get answers.